# Kong API Gateway auth works either for root path or for specific resource path, not both

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

I am using Kong API Gateway with pretty straightforward configuration.

I have two services registered, with `/` being public part of api and `/admin/{resource_id}` protected with oauth.

Second service is using following configuration, path here only:

```
routes:
  - name: admin_endpoint
    paths:
      - /admin/
    strip_path: false
```

Which works as expected for `/admin/` path e.g. GET all resources. When I add a additional paths like below:

```
routes:
  - name: admin_endpoint
    paths:
      - /admin/?$
    strip_path: false
```

Request works and token is passed to upstream and I am able to GET single resource, but on GET `/admin` token is not passed to upstream. (I am able to verify via logs that requested are routed to service `admin_endpoint` although I have service registered with `/` which doesn't have oauth configured so requests are properly routed.)

Ingress is routed via `/` directly to Kong.

So conclusion is, either I have working configuration that works on root path `/admin` or `admin/{id}` but not both.

Anyone faced similar issue?